# What's new in SharePoint 2013 Foundation?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, 2013

Now that SharePoint 2013 Preview finally got released, I am wondering - what is new in the Foundation-edition of the 2013-release?

I am hoping for some sort of light CMS-functionality for simple/small websites, but it doesn't seem to come with that yet...

Comment: Due to the nature of the question I have converted this to a Community Wiki as suggested.

Answer (score 3):

[What's new](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261970%28office.15%29.aspx)

Pertains to both SPF 2013 and SPS 2013

Comment: Yeah, I've read that once earlier. But I still think it is unclear which features only live in Server and which features also comes with Foundation..

-Guess we'll just have to wait for more info on that..

Answer (score 1):

What is SharePoint 2013 (Preview) -
A new version of Microsoft famous Collaboration portal called SharePoint. The version adds few new exciting features such as Social Feed,SharePoint Apps and cross-site publishing.
Development Changes –

   In SharePoint 2013 Microsoft Introduced a new Cloud App Model for designing Apps for SharePoint. Apps for SharePoint are self-contained pieces of functionality that extend the capabilities of a SharePoint website. You can use HTML, CSS, JavaScript and protocols like the Open Data protocol (OData), and OAuth to communicate with SharePoint using Apps.
   Tools – SharePoint 2013 has Introduced new Tools for App development. Visual Studio 2012 now lets you develop apps for SharePoint and apps for Office. In addition a new web-based tools called “Napa” Office 365 Development Tools were introduced for developing apps.
   No more Sandbox solutions. SharePoint 2013 sandboxed solutions are deprecated. So all we got is the New App model and the Old SharePoint Farm solutions. check out SharePoint 2013 – Apps Vs Farm solutions

Answer (score 0):

This is a good website with many differences between the two, at the bottom you can select to see other differences between foundation , server std and server ent.

http://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-hosting/2010/compare-sharepoint-foundation-server/

Good luck in finding a comparability check for 2013 as its only the beta version thats out at the moment but you can see from 2010 the differences to expect from 2013

Answer (score 0):

Read the New Features Comparison

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/07/25/sharepoint-2013-vs-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Hi Ravi. Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange. This question has been answered on numerous occasions before, and as such it would be better to use the search functionality before posting. Please refer to the [FAQ][1] for more information on how to post here. [1]: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: @HughWood Shouldn't we try and close this question as a duplicate then?

Comment: It got flagged.

Answer (score -1):

The following url http://www.apps4rent.com/sharepoint-2013-features-comparison.html offers a good insight into the new features offered in all the three versions of SharePoint 2013

Answer (score -3):

let me google it for you :)

[Hundred of blogs/ Websites providing Information you need](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=whats+new+in+sharepoint+foundation+2013&oq=whats+new+in+sharepoint+foundation+2013&gs_l=hp.3...445.5883.0.6027.39.37.0.0.0.1.241.3867.23j11j3.37.0...0.0...1c.fRFI4TMkr_g&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=7cc0de6fcdacacd0&biw=1600&bih=757)

If not then why dont install/try it yourself :)

**EDIT**

SharePoint Foundation and SharePoint server are edition of same product, SharePoint Server have more features then SharePoint foundation tho, I couldn't find any difference between 2013 Foundation Vs SP 2013 Server, but here is difference between SP 2010 :)

[Foundation Vs Server](http://www.beyondweblogs.com/post/DIFFERENCE-BETWEEN-SHAREPOINT-FOUNDATION-AND-SHAREPOINT-SERVER.aspx)

Comment: Don't worry - I've already googled it ... but all those results are for SharePoint 2013 **Server**-edition...

-I was asking for an overview of the changes in the Foundation-edition..

Comment: I edited my answer :)

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30361